# why is that when I save a code file in VS code as a .js file it wont run or open in a browser?

Tags: javascript, windows, visual-studio-code

Im doing practice work in creating a javascript and testing it out. like creating a box and adding javascript to change the color, size, fade, etc. im instructed to create 2 files in VS code. one named index.html and one named javascript.js. i have to copy and save a code in the html file. then it asks me to write my javascript in the javascript.js file. but it in VScode its not allowing my to open the javascript.js file. im wondering what the issue is or am i writing it in the wrong file?
here are a screen shot of what im asked to do and what im getting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFFOU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tB4iB.png)

Comment: Your HTML file is called "javascript.js" and it's calling itself in the `<script>` tag. So you missed the part where you were meant to create a separate file called `index.html`.

Comment: You wrote html code in javascript.js file.

Comment: You should write html code in `index.html` and open `index.html` file in browser not `javascript.js` file.

Comment: I think you are new in coding, first learn the basic structure of html, css and javascript and try tests.

Comment: (As an aside I probably wouldn't use my .ssh folder for development work).

Comment: thank you everyone for your feed back!. i am just starting out so i really appreciate the responses.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout your second screenshot, you have put the `html` content in a `js` file mistakenly!,
instead try this:

1. Create a `index.html` file and put the `html` content inside it
2. Create a `javascript.js` file and put the `JavaScript` content inside it.

Then open your `index.html` file in a browser.

Comment: thank you for your feed back! appreciated much